# ScreenFlow: select an area to capture or crop the video, how?

Tags: ios, video-editing

I'm trying to use ScreenFlow (together with SimFinger) to make an iPhone Simulator video.
Is it possibile to select a particular area to capture? Or how could I crop the video after the capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is posible to do in ScreenFlow. This may help.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfxWUnspy-o

Comment: This crops the *canvas* which is very different from cropping the capture.

Comment: "ScreenFlow, by design, captures full screen efficiently and then allows you to crop afterwards as gregse alludes to. It's part of the "secret sauce" of ScreenFlow that allows for larger than HD captures and reasonable file sizes. --
CraigS , 
Telestream Desktop Forum Moderator
" http://forum.telestream.net/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=42&threadid=2202

Comment: Why downvotes? Youtube link shows exactly what I wanted!

Comment: People are downvoting because this answer does not contain the actual method, it contains a link-only.  Link-only answers are not useful because **when** the link goes away, this answer has zero value.

Answer (score 11):

Press Ctrl and drag the corners of the video.

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for if you actually need to crop the *capture* and not the canvas. +1

Comment: Do you know of any way to specify the crop numerically?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works on OSX too with ScreenFlow 6.

Answer (score 3):

ScreenFlow (I'm using version 4 here) allows you to **resize the canvas**, and **crop the video clip**.  These are two separate things.

[image: Resize canvas vs Crop video]

- Resizing the canvas is done by clicking the square button at bottom left.  This affects the dimensions of your exported result.  (Eg set 500 x 400 here, and set scale to 100% when exporting to produce a result of that size.)
- Cropping the video clip is done by selecting it in the timeline, then using the Crop sliders in the Video Properties pane, or alternatively, ctrl-dragging the handles around the video.  This doesn't affect the size of the exported version: this feature is more for when you want to show multiple objects on the screen at once (eg reduce the size of your screen capture so that you can include a caption underneath it).

The entire screen is always recorded, and these adjustments must be made after the capture.

Answer (score 2):

Please use QuickTime Player.app instead.

///////////////
Software  OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)

1. Open QuickTime Player.app
2. File-->New ScreenRecording...
   [image]
3. Choose your own settings, and press the RED BUTTON.
4. Select a particular area, and then Click mouse.
5. ....
6. Stop
7. Saving

Comment: awesome... hadn't a clue that got added

Answer (score 0):

The QuickTime Player.app would have done the trick *IF* one could select the computer audio track for capture together with the video on screen. Since the functionality is not there, you need something like ScreenFlow.